# Decoding Bitwise enum get original values

Tags: c#

I have an enum like that:

```
public enum ChoixAbonnements 
    {
        Dirigeant = 1,
        InterlocuteurGestion = 2,
        Comptabilite = 4,
        InterlocuteurSyndic = 8,
        InterlocuteurInformatiqueInterne = 16,
        InterlocuteurInformatiqueLocationVacances = 32,

    }
```

I have to decoding that and to get values of these checkbox:

```
protected void CheckboxBinding() 
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<ChoixAbonnements, CheckBox>()  
        { 
            { ChoixAbonnements.Dirigeant, this.CheckBox_Dirigeant},
            { ChoixAbonnements.InterlocuteurGestion, this.CheckBox_Interlocuteur_Gestion},
            { ChoixAbonnements.Comptabilite, this.CheckBox_Comptabilite},
            { ChoixAbonnements.InterlocuteurSyndic, this.CheckBox_Interlocuteur_Syndic},
            { ChoixAbonnements.InterlocuteurInformatiqueInterne, this.Checkbox_Interlocuteur_Informatique_Interne},
            { ChoixAbonnements.InterlocuteurInformatiqueLocationVacances, this.CheckBox_Interlocuteur_LocationVacances}
        };
```

Anyone has idea?

Comment: Question is not clear, what does "I have to decoding that" mean?

Comment: The question is difficult to understand, but..

Wouldn't it be easier if you swapped your dictionary key/values so the checkbox is the key?

Comment: I assume the enum is a `[Flags]` enum?

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to get a mask indicating which enum values have been checked?  If so, you need something like this:

```
var mask = default(ChoixAbonnements);

foreach (var e in dict.Keys) {
    if (dict[e].Checked == true)
        mask |= c;
}
```

If you want to do the reverse, i.e., populate the check boxes from a mask, do something like this:

```
var mask = ...;

foreach (var e in dict.Keys) {
    dict[e].Checked = ((mask & e) == e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a value of type `ChoixAbonnements` (let's call it `myVal`), you can test each component like this:

```
var isDirigeant = (myVal & ChoixAbonnements.Dirigeant) == ChoixAbonnements.Dirigeant;
```

So you could do:

```
isDirigeantCheckBox.IsChecked = (myVal & ChoixAbonnements.Dirigeant) == ChoixAbonnements.Dirigeant;
```

Comment: `&`, not `&&`, and `(myVal & ChoixAbonnements.Dirigeant) > 0` should be sufficient, it's shorter.

Comment: @Rotem: Good catch on `&` vs `&&`, typing faster than I'm thinking. The `>0` part is stylistic. Personally I think the `==` makes the intent a little clearer, but you can certainly go either way.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried (int)ChoixAbonnements.Dirigeant ?